# Can't resize Swiper.js navigation arrows

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have a Swiper but can't resize the navigation arrows for some reason.

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  color: white !important;
  fill: white !important;
  stroke: white !important;
  width: 10px !important;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```

It does not matter what values I give, the arrows stay the same.

Comment: Hi Jaydendev, did you see my below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy and straightforward solution is to remove the default arrows and use custom ones. To do so, you need:

```css
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-button-next:after {
  display: none;
}
```

And then have for example an icon for each controller like so:

```
<div class="swiper-button-next">Custom</div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev">Custom</div>
```

Here is a working live demo to get an idea:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-items:center;
}


.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-button-next:after {
  display: none;
}

i{
 color:crimson;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></div>
</div>
```